# resnet50 (bs 128) training steps is not showing up on MAC(Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0), but showing up when training on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: tensorflow

I was using below command on both Linux and MAC, there is no problem on Linux:

python tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --model=resnet50_v2 --num_inter_threads=2   --batch_size=128 --num_batches=3000 --data_format NCHW --train_dir /tmp/output_dir  --data_name=imagenet --data_dir /xxx/xxxx/xxxx/ --datasets_use_prefetch=False --save_model_steps=10000 --print_training_accuracy=True --summary_verbosity=2  --eval_during_training_every_n_epochs=1 --num_learning_rate_warmup_epochs=5  --num_epochs_per_decay=30 --learning_rate_decay_factor=0.1 --variable_update=parameter_server  --optimizer=momentum --init_learning_rate=0.05  --num_eval_epochs=1 --save_summaries_steps=50

On my MAC, the training log is like below:

TensorFlow:  1.14

Model:       resnet50_v2

Dataset:     imagenet

Mode:        training + evaluation

SingleSess:  False

Batch size:  128 global

```
         128 per device
```

Num batches: x000

Num epochs:  0.x0

Devices:     ['/gpu:0']

NUMA bind:   False

Data format: NCHW

Optimizer:   momentum

Variables:   parameter_server

==========
Generating training model

Generating evaluation model

Initializing graph

Running warm up

Done with training

Running final evaluation at global_step xx10

10  12.7 examples/sec

20  13.1 examples/sec

**issue is:**

before "done with training", it supposed to show training steps like below, but it does not.

Running warm up

Done warm up

Step    Img/sec total_loss  top_1_accuracy  top_5_accuracy

1   images/sec: 13.1 +/- 0.0 (jitter = 0.0) 7.493   0.000   0.000

10  images/sec: 31.6 +/- 4.5 (jitter = 14.2)    7.504   0.000   0.000

20  images/sec: 31.9 +/- 2.7 (jitter = 10.7)    7.490   0.000   0.008

30  images/sec: 32.9 +/- 2.2 (jitter = 10.1)    7.515   0.000   0.000

40  images/sec: 33.4 +/- 2.0 (jitter = 12.1)    7.495   0.016   0.016

....

**on Linux,** the logs shown are correct/as expected:

TensorFlow:  1.14

Model:       resnet50_v2

Dataset:     imagenet

Mode:        training + evaluation

SingleSess:  False

Batch size:  128 global

```
         128 per device
```

Num batches: x000

Num epochs:  0.x0

Devices:     ['/gpu:0']

Data format: NCHW

Optimizer:   momentum

Variables:   parameter_server

==========
Generating training model

Generating evaluation model

Initializing graph

Running warm up
Done warm up

Step    Img/sec total_loss  top_1_accuracy  top_5_accuracy

1   images/sec: 13.1 +/- 0.0 (jitter = 0.0) 7.493   0.000   0.000

10  images/sec: 31.6 +/- 4.5 (jitter = 14.2)    7.504   0.000   0.000

20  images/sec: 31.9 +/- 2.7 (jitter = 10.7)    7.490   0.000   0.008

30  images/sec: 32.9 +/- 2.2 (jitter = 10.1)    7.515   0.000   0.000

40  images/sec: 33.4 +/- 2.0 (jitter = 12.1)    7.495   0.016   0.016

50  images/sec: 32.7 +/- 1.8 (jitter = 9.3) 7.495   0.000   0.000

60  images/sec: 33.5 +/- 1.6 (jitter = 9.4) 7.536   0.000   0.000

70  images/sec: 35.3 +/- 1.4 (jitter = 9.7) 7.521   0.000   0.000

.....

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add more details? CPU/GPU/ format the logs, there are few resnet 50 models, can you pint us to the code?

Comment: thanks gogasca. It's CPU.

Comment: Let me try it in my computer and I will get back to you

Comment: thanks gogasca, do you have any finding?